# A question about isomorphism between two groups

Tags: group-theory, permutations

Suppose that the group $G$ acts transitively on a set $X$ and $\alpha \in X$. Let $G_\alpha$ be the stabilizer of the action of $G$ on $\alpha$. Also suppose that

$$\operatorname{Aut}(X)=\{f:X \to X \mid f\in \operatorname{Sym}(X) \text{ and } f(x^g)=f(x)^g \text{ for all }g \in G \text{ and } x \in X\}$$
where $x^g$ is the image of acting an element $g \in G$ on $x \in X$.

It is easy to see that $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ is a supgroup of $\operatorname{Sym}(X)$. I want to prove that $\operatorname{Aut}(X)$ is isomorphic to the group $\cfrac{N_G(G_{\alpha})}{G_{\alpha}}$ but I don't have any useful idea.

I will be so appreciate for any helpful answers.

Comment: Note that $f$ is fully determined by $f(\alpha)$ and try to define $N_G(G_\alpha) \to \operatorname{Aut}(X)$ by $g \mapsto (\alpha \mapsto \alpha^g)$. Does that help?

Comment: @moonlight: Thank you so much because of your comment. If we denote $f_g:\alpha \mapsto \alpha ^g$, why $f_g(x^h)=f_g(x)^h$ for all $h \in G$ and also, why is your function surjective?

Comment: Every $x \in X$ is in the orbit of $\alpha$ by transitivity. If $x=\alpha^k$ with $k \in G$, then $f_g(x) = \alpha^{gk}$ (use this as definition, check that it is well-defined). Then $f_g(x^h)=f_g(\alpha^{kh})=\alpha^{gkh} = f_g(x)^h$. For surjectivity check that if $f \in \operatorname{Aut}(X)$, and $f(\alpha) = \alpha^g$, then $g \in N_G(G_\alpha)$ by calculating $\alpha^g=f(\alpha)=f(\alpha^h)=f(\alpha)^h=\alpha^{gh}$ for $h \in G_\alpha$. Note that I am leaving all the technical details for you to check!

Comment: Btw, if you are familiar with the fact that every group action of $G$ on $X$ corresponds to a group homomorphism $G \to \operatorname{Sym}(X)$, it will probably be shorter to use this as the starting point.

Comment: Oh, I just realized I may have made some mistakes with respect to left/right actions. If you have right actions but are writing functions on the left (as usual), I think you'll have to map $g \mapsto f_g$ where $f_g(\alpha) = \alpha^{g^{-1}}$ to find $f_{gh}=f_{g}\circ f_h$. So you probably have to make some adjustments of this kind, but the overall idea must work.

Comment: @moonlight: Thank you very much because of your helpful guidance.